# Using the update-goal of Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, maven, liquibase

Im trying to automate the database-processes. As far as I understood it, by using Liquibase I can invoke the changes made in changesetLog-file automatically with the `<goal>` tag.

But when I extend my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5</version>
  <configuration>
    ..
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Eclipse shows me this error:

`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.5: (execution: default, phase: process-resources)`

Any idea how to solve this?? And what the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration (JBossas 7 EAR archetype)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype)

Comment: While the question may possibily have the same root cause, I think it's unfair to expect the author to find the other answer in a stackoverflow search.

Comment: @Duncun Thanks for the hint. Putting simple "ignore" worked.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor That's why I didn't suffix my statement with "... you search illiterate moron!" :-)  Duplicates are duplicates, regardless of how buried they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The liquibase has several [available goals](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven). You neglected to specify "update".

```
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

For a liquibase example see the following question:

- [Lock oracle database before running the Delete/Load data scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794169/lock-oracle-database-before-running-the-delete-load-data-scripts/10804663#10804663)

Comment: No, sadly I neglected to specify "update" only here. In my code its present.

Comment: Did you read Duncan's link? Specifically the referenced page here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Comment: Thanks Mark. Like I said above to Duncun putting simple "ignore" worked. Making things more complicated then they are was never smart.